# How to do a fresh install while keeping the @home btrfs subvolume with encrypted home folder

Tags: system-installation, encryption, btrfs

I have Kubuntu 16.04 installed on my computer, but the system has been having worsening problems since I upgraded from 15.10, and I'd like to do a fresh install while keeping my home folder intact. My main drive has a btrfs filesystem (so the home directory is in the @home subvolume) and I have an encrypted home folder. I have backed up the @home subvolume to a secondary drive.

Does the following procedure make sense?

1. Reformat the main drive (again with btrfs)
2. Reinstall Kubuntu on the main drive.
3. Delete the new @home subvolume on the main drive.
4. Copy the backup of the old @home subvolume from the secondary drive to the main drive

I'm pretty sure that this procedure would work if my home folder were no encrypted. However, will my encrypted home folder cause problems, or will Kubuntu handle the encrypted home folder automatically? Maybe I'd just have to use the same login password for the fresh install as for the previous install?